# position text on both sides of zurb 6 range slider

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to have text on both edges (right and left) of the slider. It's very clear why this makes sense from a UX perspective. Obviously that's not working for me:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="small-10 small-centered columns"> 
            <fieldset class="fieldset ">
              <legend style="background:0;">bla bla</legend>
                <div style="color:#1583cc">left extreme name</div>
                  <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-initial-end="100">
                    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput2"></span>
                    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
                  </div>
                  <div style="color:#1583cc">right extreme name</div>           
          <div class="row">
                   <div class="small-1 small-centered columns">
                  <input type="number" id="sliderOutput2" style="text-align:center; color: #1583cc;">
                  </div>
                  </div>
          </fieldset>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The texts become their own row while the slider takes up the entire width of the container as a third row in between them.

I'd like them to be one row, where the slider occupies the space left after the texts have been positioned at the (left and right) edges of the container's width. How should that be accomplished in a nice way?

Comment: Also being the Zurb newb that I am, can't seem to get a round fieldset and  a center-aligned value in the slider-bounded input field, because the up/down arrows of the input field take up their space also when the input field is not in focus.... just in case you're feeling really generous :-)

Comment: Nor can I make the slider slide through real numbers between 0 and 1 rather than through integers. I guess that's just not supported.

Comment: You should ask the other questions on their own. They will be answered.

Answer (score 1):

As a newb to the Zurb Foundation, you should look into the grid system which allows you to do just what you are asking. It is also the basis for the responsive design.

Your code:

```
<div style="color:#1583cc">left extreme name</div>
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-initial-end="100">
    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput2"></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
</div>
<div style="color:#1583cc">right extreme name</div>
```

... should utilize the grid. Here is an example but there are many ways you could go about it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-3 columns" style="color:#1583cc">left extreme name</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-initial-end="100">
            <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput2"></span>
            <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns" style="color:#1583cc">right extreme name</div>
</div>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/slider.html#data-binding

Here is the info on grids (and more basics) you should study:

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#basics